# Koala support for multiple FB Apps at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm initializing Koala with one FB App's info (app id, secret, callback url) and that is the usual one that I need to use for making graph api calls.

However, I need to occasionally make calls within the same RoR process to the FB graph api for a different FB App. What's the best way to do this for one-off calls that I need to make for the 2nd FB App? I thought initializing a new object like this would work, but it still seems to be using the original app info:

```
k = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user_fb_token, APP_2_SECRET)
```

Ideally, it can support multiple apps at the same time so that I don't have to worry about other calls accidentally using the 2nd app if I re-initialize Koala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case it's still open - you can easily use Koala for several FB apps at the same time. 
The thing is that your user_fb_token is dependent upon app, not a general user token. It's actually `user_fb_token_for_app_1`, and `user_fb_token_for_app_2`. And then you create two instances of Koala for two different tokens.

As a side effect, you would need to follow two login procedures for each app to get two tokens for the same user.

*Useful link*: Access Token "debugger" by FB to see details on token:

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/?q=

There you would see that user token actually belongs to specific fb app.

Comment: thanks, pavel.  i've checked with the fb access token debugger and it shows that the token was created with the correct fb app.  the issue is that when i try to make a call with that user token (for app 2) using our singleton Koala object, it only returns basic info from FB.  it turns out that the issue (i think) was a difference in the version settings (within the dev console on FB) between the 2 FB apps.  the older version returned more fields by default with a call to get the object "me", while the newer app didn't.